# No Fortran Heroku Scipy Install

Tags: python, heroku, scipy, installation

How to install Scipy on Heroku ?

I was trying to use https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy

I have no problem with install numpy. But when I install Scipy there is a problem.

library error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too; I was trying to use Scipy in a Django app. The problem was fixed by simply putting numpy and Scipy at the top of my requirements.txt. That is:

Before:

`dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8.4
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
numpy==1.9.2
psycopg2==2.6.1
scipy==0.15.1
static3==0.6.1
wheel==0.24.0`

After: 

`numpy==1.9.2
scipy==0.15.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8.4
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
static3==0.6.1
wheel==0.24.0`